# What happens with old jwt token in vert.x?

Tags: jwt, vert.x

Does it just expire at the same time when the new one was generated or it still lives for some specified period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWTs by design can't be revoked. A JWT is valid until it expires, which is the date from the `exp` claim. There are solutions where you can blacklist JWTs and treat them as expired, but I don't think that vert.x implements such a solution.